# How can I change the fragments on button click?

Tags: java, spring-boot, android-studio, android-fragments

**I'm having a problem with changing from one fragment to another when pressing a button "menuButton" in my Andorid Studio application.**

*LoginActivity.java*

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityLoginBinding binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

        Button menu = findViewById(R.id.menuButton);

         //switch to register fragment
        menu.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            RegisterFragment registerFragment = RegisterFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.login_text, registerFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        });
    }
}
```

**The two fragments are fragment_login.xml and fragment_register.xml**

**The result I am getting are switching to the Registration fragment but it displays over the login fragment.**

Note: I am new to posting questions so if you need more info just tell me so.

Comment: What result are you getting ? Please clearly mention what results are you getting. Also please check if ```login_text``` is the accurate id ?

Comment: @BadriPaudel I updated the question with the results I am getting. login_text is the accurate id of FragmentContainerView which was previously in other fragment but I moved the view and the button here because the previous button was showing over my "login" button on the loginFragment.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint using debug mode in IDE and see if value is not null ? Is RegisterFragment.newInstance() gives same as new RegisterFragment();

Comment: @BadriPaudel so I made a new instance registerFragment1 with "new RegisterFragment()" and I attached breakpoints and this is the result from debuging:

registerFragment= RegisterFragment{4d8e393} (40aafede-7af3-472b-bcea-4e167bf76ce3)
registerFragment1 = RegisterFragment{c61dfd0} (76370233-9759-4913-9830-5d87b8c3c44d)

Comment: what result are you getting when you do ```RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();``` Actually it should work. Code seems correct but your details ins't enough.  Make sure, login_text layout has proper width and height set so that new fragment is visible. If you're getting any type of error , please post the error too. Without details, it is very hard to answer. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions on SO.